# Angular 1.5 Option with ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

We have this JSON

```
{
  "Day": "Monday",
  "Start_Time": "08:00"
},
{
  "Day": "Tuesday",
  "Start_Time": "10:00"
},
{
  "Day": "Thursday",
  "Start_Time": "08:00"
}
```

So I'm trying to make these days appear inside an html `select` item with those options. Something like this

```
<select>
 <option>Monday 08:00</option>
 <option>Tuesday 10:00</option>
 <option>Thursday 08:00</option>
</select>
```

And when the user changes the option i would like to print out the new option that he made, here i'm stuck.

What I've done till now.

```
  <select ng-if="student.diwro" >
                    <option ng-repeat="x in modules" ng-selected="student.diwro == x.Anatheseis_Id" >{{x.Day}} {{x.Start_Time}}</option>
                  </select>
```

But html element `option` has no `ng-change`.

Any idea of how can I console log the changed day ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why dont you put an ng-change in the select box?

Comment: also, you can use `ng-options` for that

Comment: @Sravan i've read that abovr Angular 1.4 there is no ng-option. Is that true?

Comment: I done think so, [angular 1.5.8](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/docs/api/ng/directive/ngOptions), 1.5.8 also has it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<select ng-if="student.diwro" ng-change="change()" ng-model="selectedValue">
    <option ng-repeat="x in modules" ng-selected="student.diwro == x.Anatheseis_Id" >{{x.Day}} {{x.Start_Time}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why don't you try it as simple select rather than to make it so complex.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-options` which can be more customizable,

```js
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){
$scope.student = {}
    $scope.modules = [
        {
            "key": "all",
            "value": "For any event on all my projects"
        },
        {
            "key": "selected",
            "value": "For any event on the selected projects only..."
        },
        {
            "key": "only_my_events",
            "value": "Only for things I watch or I'm involved in"
        },
        {
            "key": "only_assigned",
            "value": "Only for things I am assigned to"
        },
        {
            "key": "only_owner",
            "value": "Only for things I am the owner of"
        },
        {
            "key": "none",
            "value": "No events"
        }
    ];

$scope.setdiwro = function()
{
alert($scope.student.diwro.key)
}
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        {{message}} <br />
        
        <!--Options value is defualt 0, 1 ... and it's non change able -->
        <span>Default Otions:</span>
        
 <select ng-model="student.diwro" ng-options="x.key for x in modules" ng-change="setdiwro()">
            <option value="">Select A Value</option>
</select>
        <br />
    
        <br />                
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because my `select` is inside a `td` and i have many, When i try your example i just get 1 alert of undefined and then nothing changes.

Comment: can you use ng-options?

Comment: If you can use `ng-options` refer my updated answer, your requirement may be something like that

Comment: @Kwnstantinos Natsios, pls run my answer once, is it correct?